# how to use a dynamic inner column outside the select

Tags: mysql

i have this query and i get error in mysql

**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'calc_diff_free' in 'field list'**

I understand the problem, but how can i use this column without changing too much

**I filtered the query to hide some data and to help you guys to read the query better**

```
insert into ranking_1 (difference_free)
(
 select 
 f.ranking, rc.ranking,
(-1*(f.ranking-rc.ranking)) as calc_diff_free
     from base_testing.ranking_temp f
     left join ranking_1 rc
     on f.id=rc.id
     where 1
 ) 
on duplicate key update difference_free=calc_diff_free
```

**Thanks for your help!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i manage to get it working...

```
insert into ranking_1 (difference_free)
(
 select 
 f.ranking, rc.ranking,
 (-1 * (f.ranking-rc.ranking)) calc_diff_free
     from base_testing.ranking_temp f
     left join ranking_1 rc
     on f.id=rc.id
     where 1
 ) 
on duplicate key update difference_free=-1*(f.ranking-rc.ranking)
```

But it's give me a few warnings...

85672 row(s) affected,Records: 42883, Duplicates: 42789, Warnings: 4

Answer (score 1):

The `on duplicate key update` clause in your query is outside the scope of the select item where the column `calc_diff_free` is declared.

You may need to recast your query to put it in scope.

Comment: i know... but how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

```
insert into ranking_1 (difference_free)
select -1 * (f.ranking-rc.ranking) as calc_diff_free
from base_testing.ranking_temp f
            left join ranking_1 rc
                    on f.id=rc.id
on duplicate key update difference_free = calc_diff_free
```

Point: *you must have equal number of columns in your `insert` and `select` clause*.

Comment: your answer was not the solution...

but added me more knowledge in mysql :)